# linear-gradient display on select

Tags: javascript

```
function colorPattern(){
    var color_Board = $('#colorBoard');
    var color_Pattern_box = ["red", "pink", "skyblue"];
    var color_temp = ('');

    for(var c = 0; c < color_Pattern_box.length; c++){
        color_temp += "<optgroup style='background:linear-gradient("+color_Pattern_box[c]+", #ffffff);'><option>"+color_Pattern_box[c]+"</option></optgroup>";
    }

    color_Board.html(color_temp);

    }

colorPattern();
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Tedeee/d3yLbbc1/)

my intention is to make a color pattern on select using linear-gradient , but i could not make it work. can anyone help me take a look what i did wrong?

Comment: i tested it with firefox and this work, in chrome not. you need to add something like -webkit-linear-gradient(#eee .1em, transparent .1em);

Comment: When you say *make a color pattern on select using linear-gradient*, that is make the select element take the color of the option when selected?

Comment: sorry how if i wanted the drop down show each color too ?

Answer (score 1):

Adding an event listener to the select will do it:

```
//if you want to make the select take a default color as the first option
color_Board.css({background: color_Board.find("option:eq(0)").parent().css("background-image")});

color_Board.on('change', function(e){
   $(this).css({background: $(this).find("option:selected").parent().css("background-image") });
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/d3yLbbc1/5/)

Comment: very nice demo by adding option :selected

Comment: what if i want it to show on the drop down ? each option show they color too ?

Comment: @Hacktor Oh, I just checked, on Firefox it shows the color while on Chrome not...

Comment: @Hacktor Well, I don't see where the problem comes from. I think a reset is needed.... You're welcome...

Answer (score 0):

Try add "-webkit-" to those "linear-gradient" prefix for compatibility with Chrome

linear-gradient is one of the many CSS3 properties what needs to be vendor specified.